# How to pass ItemGroup with metadata between targets?

Tags: msbuild

From my understanding, using `DependsOnTargets` is necessary to pass ItemGroup between targets.  I am not sure if there are other ways to pass targets without `DependsOnTargets`.

I have tested that ItemGroup cannot pass from `CallTarget` or `MSBuild` task.  A workaround solution is convert the ItemGroup to property (flatten it) and use `Properties` to pass over.

I define a `ItemGroup` of `File`.  The `File` has `Value` metadata.  I would like to execute target and remove one `File` item for each recursive loop.  Here is my script:

```
<Target Name="MyGroup">
  <ItemGroup>
    <File Include="5">
      <Value>5a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="4">
      <Value>4a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="3">
      <Value>3a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="2">
      <Value>2a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="1">
      <Value>1a</Value>
    </File>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="Recursive" DependsOnTargets="MyGroup" Condition="$(Value) > 0">
  <ItemGroup>
    <File Remove="$(Value)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Value>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Value), 1))</Value>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="File: @(File->'%(Value)') Value=$(Value)" Importance="High" />
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" Properties="Value=$(Value)"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="MyGroup">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" Properties="Value=5" />
</Target>
```

The output is:

```
File: 4a;3a;2a;1a Value=4
File: 5a;3a;2a;1a Value=3
File: 5a;4a;2a;1a Value=2
File: 5a;4a;3a;1a Value=1
File: 5a;4a;3a;2a Value=0
```

I expect the output to be:

```
File: 4a;3a;2a;1a Value=4
File: 3a;2a;1a Value=3
File: 2a;1a Value=2
File: 1a Value=1
File: Value=0
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, you are trying to circumvent idea of msbuild to build target only once (unless inputs\outputs changes). 
And you can't pass itemgroups between MSBuild contexts (when you call MSBuild task - new context is created). Also in your script - ItemGroup is scoped to target - you need to define it globally so it'll be available to other targets. 
What you can do is:

- Define Global property Value with condition to use the one passed to script if exists.
- Change ItemGroup from MyGroup target to global scope.
- Define conditions on each element of itemgroup to be emitted depending on the value of Value property

e.g. your script will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Value Condition="$(Value) == ''">5</Value>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <File Include="5" Condition="$(Value) >5">
      <Value>5a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="4" Condition="$(Value) >4">
      <Value>4a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="3" Condition="$(Value) >3">
      <Value>3a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="2" Condition="$(Value) >2">
      <Value>2a</Value>
    </File>
    <File Include="1" Condition="$(Value) >1">
      <Value>1a</Value>
    </File>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Recursive" Condition="$(Value) >0">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Value>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Value), 1))</Value>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="File: @(File->'%(Value)') Value=$(Value)" Importance="High" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" Properties="Value=$(Value)"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" Properties="Value=5" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

---

As [Alexey Shcherbak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25443/alexey-shcherbak) points out, we can't pass `ItemGroup` from `MSBuild` task.  I resolve my problem by introducing a new property `Done` to keep a list of item that has processed.

```
<Target Name="MyGroup">
    <ItemGroup>
        <File Include="5">
            <Value>5a</Value>
        </File>
        <File Include="4">
            <Value>4a</Value>
        </File>
        <File Include="3">
            <Value>3a</Value>
        </File>
        <File Include="2">
            <Value>2a</Value>
        </File>
        <File Include="1">
            <Value>1a</Value>
        </File>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="Recursive" DependsOnTargets="MyGroup" Condition="$(Value) > 0" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <File Remove="$(Value)" />
        <File Remove="$(Done)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="File: @(File->'%(Value)') Value=$(Value)" Importance="High" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Done>$(Done);$(Value)</Done>
        <Value>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Value), 1))</Value>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" Properties="Value=$(Value);Done=$(Done)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="MyGroup">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Recursive" Properties="Value=5" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I couldn't build the ItemGroup using the `Condition` attribute in my actual project.  The example given is a prototype to show problems I face.  Those Items were a set of files in my project.

Comment: MSBuild script is not really "procedural language to build your project", so if you have no or little control over itemgroups - then the answer to your question is no (at least afaik) - msbuild will process all global properties and items before any target calls and items can be added to these, but not removed. Can you describe what are you trying to achieve and maybe there is another solution to the problem which doesn't require recursive calls ? EDIT: Umm sorry, didn't noticed your answer. I'm happy you've resolved your problem using another approach

Comment: My problem is I have a group of `Delphi` project (290++) to build.  There are dependency relations between these projects.  I have successfully build the dependency relations from these projects and keep it in `ItemGroup` using item metadata to keep dependency information.  First, I filter a list of projects that don't have dependency from the `ItemGroup` and perform the build task in parallel manner. I then remove dependency of new build object files from the ItemGroup.  In second loop, I filter again.  These operations will perform in recursive manner using `MSBuild`.

Comment: Are you building Delphi projects with MSBuild e.g. calling your own compiler in exec or something ? Why are you using MSBuild for that rather than any other scripting language ? I'm not sure why you choose MSBuild but I'd say it's mediocre as a batch build language for anything other than .NET. It shines for .NET builds because all build procedures are tied to work with it. And your problem in .NET probably will be resolved easily - just build the output project and all dependencies will be built automatically.

Comment: `Delphi` use `MSBuild` since 2007 to build a group of projects (`groupproj` and `dproj` files).  More info: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Building_a_Project_Using_an_MSBuild_Command

Comment: Interesting. Then why do you need these recursive things - if it's "native" msbuild support then you need to build only top-level project (starting one e.g. winform-equivalent app or deployable service) and all dependencies will be built automatically.

Comment: I have 290 projects.  The original `MSBuild` script from `Delphi` build these project one by one.  It takes more than 100 seconds to build using a single core only.  if I build these projects with 4C/2T CPU with `BuildInParallel=True`, it takes about 24 seconds only.  My intention is create a `MSBuild` script to utilize multi-core CPU for my projects.

Comment: Try to build your main project with BuildInParallel="True" and Msbuild should handle the rest - it'll use all allowed CPUs to build dependant projects.